# how to exclude (directory or files) from coverage report

Tags: python, django, jenkins, django-jenkins

I am using django-jenkins and am trying to get jenkins to ignore a folder in my app in the coverage report.

I have found the option --coverage-exclude from https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins/blob/master/django_jenkins/tasks/with_coverage.py, but cant seem to get it to work.

so far i have tried:

```
python [project]/manage.py jenkins [app] --coverage-exclude=COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS
```

with

```
COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS = (
    '[app]/[dir to be excluded]/*'
)
```

and various combinations of path names

and also

```
python [project]/manage.py jenkins [app] --coverage-exclude='[path to dir]'
```

can anyone give me an idea of how i use this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues getting the migrations ignored during the coverage report, and found the following to work

```
COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS = ['people/migrations/*']
```

Rather than

```
COVERAGE_EXCLUDES_FOLDERS = ('people/migrations/*')
```

Comment: you just need a comma before the closing `)` if you want to use the `tuple` version. That is because `('')` in python is not a tuple but `('',)` is.